# jQuery if-else working 50%

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

The code below is inside a document.ready function. The if-else statement works only half the way... the first part (if) works fine, and I made an alert after powerClicked to show me if it's setting powerClicked to 1, and it is. The else if does absolutely nothing... Anyone seeing my error? I don't know if something might be bugging the jQuery, the entire HTML is being rendered over ReactJS VDOM.

```js
var powerClicked = 0;
    
    if(powerClicked == 0) {
        $('#Power').click(function() {
            powerClicked = 1;
           $('#Power').animate({
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)' 
           }, 1500);
            //fading in text
        $('#boxText').delay(2000).fadeIn(500).text('Listening');
        
        });
        
    } else if(powerClicked == 1) {
        $('#Power').click(function() {
            
           $('#Power').animate({
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)' 
           }, 1500); 
           //fading out text
            $('boxText').fadeOut(500);
            powerClicked = 0;
        });   
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: right, I think one of serveral errors is that you're expecting this code to be executed everytime `$('#Power')`'s value changes, but it does not. this code is executed only once the `document` is `ready` and that happens only one time. other error here is that doing `var powerClicked = 0;` right before the `if` statement is not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your code runs, the `if` statement runs and creates the function to handle clicks for the `$('#Power')` element.

Whenever the `$('#Power')` element is clicked, the function defined within it will be triggered.  The `if-else` will never execute again.  You need to move the `if-else` logic within the click handler.  Something like this should work:

```
    var powerClicked = false;
    $('#Power').click(function() {
       powerClicked = !powerClicked;

       if (powerClicked) {
         $('#Power').animate({
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)' 
         }, 1500);
       } else {
         $('#Power').animate({
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)' 
         }, 1500); 

       }

       //fading in text
       $('#boxText').delay(2000).fadeIn(500).text('Listening');        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('boxText')` you need to change it to `$('#boxText')` so that it correctly grabs the element node (assuming it has an **id** of "boxText"